# Error when trying to run a query via bq cli

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm getting the following error when trying to execute the bq query:

```
FATAL Flags parsing error: Unknown command line flag '-v'
```

The query is simple and I think the problem is inside the concat function, because I'm trying to concat a curl command and there I have a -v flag, the query is below:

```
select concat('curl -v https://api.com.br/push.json  -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -H \"x_application: WebApp\" -H -X POST -d \'{\"pushes\":[\''
    ,string_agg(to_json_string(t)),']}\'') as json
```

How can I escape the -v to not getting this error?

Thanks

Comment: are you using the select statement to build curl command that then you execute outside of BigQuery and that is where you are getting error?

Comment: Yes, exactly this @MikhailBerlyant

Comment: So you should know which command line you want to build  - right - this looks to me like curl related more than bigquery. so what is the curl command you expect to build and how it is different from what you get by running above query?

Comment: I don't quite understand. When you run `bq query "select concat(...)"` you get the error message or after you get the return of the select statement and run the resulting `curl` command is that you get the error message?

Comment: Hi @MikhailBerlyant, the problem is not in curl, I'm trying to build a curl command inside bigquery, the query is running perfectly in bigquery wepapp, but is not running when I ran on bigquery command line.

Comment: @WillianFuks I'm getting the error message when I try to run the query in bigquery command line.

Comment: yes, i realized it - but still the way you tailored your question makes it too fuzzy for me at least to answer it. you presented the query only which leaves us to guess what else you have there - i recommend you to present your whole code so it will be more realistic to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running this:

```
bq query "select concat('curl -v https://api.com.br/push.json  -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -H \"x_application: WebApp\" -H -X POST -d \'{\"pushes\":[\'',string_agg(to_json_string(t)),']}\'') as json"
```

In order to prevent bash interpretation from the string, maybe reading the query from a file might help as well. If your query is something like:

```
WITH data AS(
select [1, 2] AS t
)

select
concat('curl -v https://api.com.br/push.json  -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -H \"x_application: WebApp\" -H -X POST -d \'{\"pushes\":[\'',string_agg(to_json_string(t)),']}\'') as json
FROM
data
```

You could save it for instance in a file "query.sql" and then run the command:

```
cat query.sql | bq query --use_legacy_sql=False
```